# Sleep Function in Python not allowing previous info to update

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guis I am making just a basic login program while getting to know tkinter, but I am running into one problem. If you run the following code, when you hit login the status label doesn't update to green and "valid" instead the login button just stays pressed in for 5 seconds then the window gets destroyed.

```
import tkinter  # import tkinter module
from time import sleep  # import sleep

# define global variables for functions to access
window, main_window, text_status, status, ent, ent2, ent3 = None, None, None, None, None, None, None


def get_input():
    global window, text_status, status, ent, ent2, ent3

    username = ent.get()

    password = ent2.get()

    verified_password = ent3.get()

    num_digits = 0

    for char in password:
        if char.isdigit():
            num_digits += 1

    # loop repeats while:
    # there are less than 2 numbers in the password
    # the passwords length is less than 6 or greater than 10
    if password == verified_password and num_digits >= 2 and 10 >= len(password) >= 6:
        status["fg"] = "green"
        text_status.set("Valid (%s, %s)" % (username, password))

        # open userfile and save userinfo
        with open("userfile.txt","a") as userfile:
            userfile.write(username + " " + password + " " + verified_password + " ")

        sleep(5)
        window.destroy()

    elif password != verified_password:
        status["fg"] = "red"
        text_status.set("Passwords don't match")

    else:
        status["fg"] = "red"
        text_status.set("Not Valid")
        print("Pass must be between 6 - 10 (inclusive) chars and contain 2 numbers. Note Password is case sensitive")

def new_user():

    global window, main_window, text_status, status, ent, ent2, ent3

    # close startup window
    main_window.destroy()

    window = tkinter.Tk()  # create a new window
    window.title("Login Screen")  # specifies window title
    #window.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')  # changes icon
    window.geometry("200x170")  # specifies window size

    #Username and password status label
    text_status = tkinter.StringVar()
    text_status.set("Not Valid")
    status = tkinter.Label(window, textvariable=text_status, fg="red")


    un_lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Username:")  # create new label
    ent = tkinter.Entry(window)  # create a text entry widget
    ps_lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Password:")
    ent2 = tkinter.Entry(window)
    v_ps_lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Verify Password:")
    ent3 = tkinter.Entry(window)
    btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Login", command=get_input)  # create a button

    # pack (add) widgets into window
    status.pack()
    un_lbl.pack()
    ent.pack()
    ps_lbl.pack()
    ent2.pack()
    v_ps_lbl.pack()
    ent3.pack()
    btn.pack()

    window.mainloop()  # draw the window and start application


def login():
    return


def startup():

    global main_window

    main_window = tkinter.Tk()
    main_window.title("Welcome")
    # main_window.geometry("500x100")

    greeting = tkinter.Label(main_window, text="Hello please choose one of the following")
    login_button = tkinter.Button(main_window, text="Login", command=login)
    mk_acc_button = tkinter.Button(main_window, text="Make Account", command=new_user)

    #greeting.pack()
    #login_button.pack()
    #mk_acc_button.pack()

    greeting.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)
    login_button.grid(column=0, row=1)
    mk_acc_button.grid(column=1, row=1)

    main_window.mainloop()

startup()
```

Answer (score 0):

`mainloop` isn't threaded AFAIK. This means that any sleeps and other deleys affect the running of the loop.

I suggest you use an asynchronous timer of some kind.

Comment: This doesn't help me man. Need to wait a bit before the window get destoyed not run the program after a while user .after()

Comment: Then your question isn't clear enough.